# can't get syntax highlighting to work with R code in vim

Tags: linux, vim, r, syntax-highlighting

This is a naive (and likely dumb) question, but I can't seem to get the R syntax highlighting to work with my Linux setup.

I've downloaded a `r.vim` file that has improved syntax highlighting, and it works on my Windows gvim setup.  Does this `r.vim` file need to be in the `/usr/share/vim/v70/syntax` directory?  Right now, I have it in my home directory and trying out `source ~/r.vim` in the `~/.vimrc` file.  However, this doesn't seem to do anything.  Perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I ran across this with a similar problem.  I have the syntax highlighting working but not the folding in vim.

Answer (score 8):

Try adding this line to the file `filetype.vim`. `filetype.vim` is generally located in the folder `~/.vim`. Create the file if it doesn't exist.

```
au! BufNewFile,BufRead *.R,*.Rout,*.r,*.Rhistory,*.Rt,*.Rout.save,*.Rout.fail setf r
```

On startup, vim links all the file extensions listed above to the filetype r, which is likely used by your syntax file. Your syntax file will not define the file extension for you typically.

See this [reference](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Filetype.vim) for more information. For syntax highlighting, this [tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I had to make a minor edit to get this working on my setup: au! BufNewFile,BufRead *.R,*.Rout,*.r,*.Rhistory,*.Rt,*.Rout.save,*.Rout.fail set filetype=R

Answer (score 7):

Is the file type getting detected?

```
:set ft?
```

That should print out something like `filetype=r` in your case.  If it's not set, try:

```
:set ft=r
```

Still nothing?  Try:

```
:syntax on
```

I place all downloaded plugins in `~/.vim/plugins/`.  You shouldn't have to place any plugins in the system folders.

In your `.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin on
syntax on
```

Comment: Alas, I've tried all those steps and still can't get it work!

Comment: No, syntax scripts belong in ~/.vim/syntax/.

Comment: Thanks for the ":set ft?" and ":set ft=r"
It was useful for me: the filetype for my .R files was set to "rexx"

Answer (score 3):

Couple of guesses:

- you are running vim-tiny (which doesn't have syntax highlighting) instead of vim-full or vim-gnome
- you do not have 'syntax on' in ~/.vimrc
- you have a permissions problem on the snippet

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I'm running the full vim and syntax is on, so I'm still puzzled.  I guess my main question is if the `r.vim` file needs to be in the syntax directory of the `/usr/share/vim` directory, or if there is some kind of work around.

Answer (score 1):

There are several R plugins for vim.

Check out [Vim-R-Plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628). It supports syntax highlighting.